# How do I intern a var in clojurescript

Tags: clojurescript

In clojure if I want to intern a var in another namespace I can use the `intern`

`(intern 'other-ns 'my-var (fn [x] x))`

I want to achieve the same thing in clojurescript, where I define a var/function in one namespace and intern it in another namespace.

I need this because I'm writing code in `cljc` and I'm interning a `var` in clojure, and I also need it to be compatible with `cljs`

Comment: Just to rule out an X-Y-problem: would you mind sharing, why you want to intern vars in other namespaces? Do you want to _replace_ or _add_? My gut-feeling teels me, that if it does not work it won't - and you would have to do that at runtime in JS?

Comment: I have a custom macro that I use to debug, I can intern it in clojure.core so I don't have to explicitly import it in every namespace, and it's available everywhere. I want to do the same thing in clojurescript. So I want to add a macro that is available everywhere in clojurescript.

Answer (score 0):

Interning is [not supported in ClojureScript](https://clojurescript.org/about/differences#_vars_and_the_global_environment): "`intern` not implemented - no reified Vars"